# Firefox add-on to check SSL certificates for changes

Tags: security, firefox, ssl

I am looking for a Firefox add-on that checks SSL serial numbers or fingerprints and reports changes to the user. I realise that SSL certificates can change at any time for many legitimate reasons, but that's okay. I am just looking for a notification that the security of a connection to a site has been changed.

There are quite a lot of add-ons for Firefox that do things with SSL certificates, but everything I've found so far is not compatible with Firefox Quantum. For example, [Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/) looks like it would do what I want but it isn't compatible with modern Firefox.